# Attaching end listener to filestream in a promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-io, es6-promise, node-streams

While studying nodejs streams, I wanted to check what happens if the `end` listener is added after a filestream has been consumed and closed.
I am puzzled by what happens: no error event, no exception thrown, but the promise is not awaited and the node process is closed with return value 0:

```
const fs = require("node:fs");
const { setTimeout } = require("node:timers/promises");

run()
    .then(() => console.log("done"))
    .catch(console.error);

async function run() {
    const myStream = fs.createReadStream(__filename);

    myStream.on("data", () => console.log("stream data"));
    myStream.on("error", (error) => console.log("stream error", error));
    myStream.on("close", () => console.log("stream close"));

    console.log("data listener added");

    await setTimeout(2000);

    await new Promise((resolve) => {
        console.log("add end listener");

        myStream.on("end", () => {
            console.log("stream end");
            resolve();
        });

        console.log("end listener added");
    });

    console.log("run end");
}
```

Output (the process stops immediately after printing this, it does not hang):

```
$ node stream1.js 
data listener added
stream data
stream close
add end listener
end listener added
```

I get that "stream end" is not reached, not pleasant but I can work with it by first checking for stream.isClosed.
As a consequence it seems logical that "run end" is not reached: I expect the `run` function to wait for the promise forever.
But why the process does not hang?
Can some nodejs expert explain what is happening?
Did I make an error with my promise handling?

I am using node v18.12.1 on Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add the `end` listener to your stream, it *has* already ended, therefore the listener will never be invoked. `resolve()` is never executed and the `await new Promise(...)` never comes to an end. Therefore, `run end` is not logged either. And the promise returned by `run` never resolves so that `done` is also not logged.

On the other hand, after `end listener added` has been logged, the event loop of Node.js is empty: there is nothing more to expect, because the file has been read. In such a situation, the Node.js process exits.

Just attaching a listener to an event does not make Node.js wait. Perhaps the following analogy helps:

```js
http.createServer().on("request", express());
```

registers a request handler but then exists immediately. By contrast, the `.listen` method makes the HTTP server wait for incoming requests, even if they are ignored because no request handler is registered at all:

```js
http.createServer().listen(8080);
```

never exits.

Also, pending promises do not make Node.js wait. Compare

```js
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(resolve, 5000);
});
```

which exits after 5 seconds, to

```js
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
});
```

which exists immediately. It is not the promise that makes Node.js wait, but the `setTimeout`.

You made no error, only a wrong expectation perhaps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I understand your 1st paragraph, this is what I expected. But I am surprised by the second: yes we (programmers) know that the process can safely exit here because we know about the end event. But how does it (node) know this? Does it know about the end event / filestreams, etc? What if I attached to a custom event? I feel a bit lost here.

Comment: I have tried to add an explanation to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the additional explanation. I am still puzzled by this: yes, attaching the event does not make node wait, but the promise is left pending, right? And awaiting a pending promise should make node wait, shouldn't it?

Comment: No. Pending promises do not make Node.js wait. I remember that fact puzzled me as well at first.

Comment: That is surprising: awaiting pending promises doesn't make node wait!!! I see more discussion about it here: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/22088 Thank you for having taken time to articulate this.