# How to run an external script with the completion of all promises in it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I need to sequentially launch external scripts with such a condition that the following code is launched only after the completion of the entire contents of the external script, including promises. I use `shell.js`, but perhaps there are other tools. I need to run the script without importing into the "parent".

External script code (external.js):

```
const fs = require("fs");
const util = require("util");

const write = util.promisify(fs.writeFile);

(async () => {
  await write("Hello.txt", "Hello");
})();
```

The "parent" code from which it is called:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const util = require("util");
const shell = require("shelljs");

const read = util.promisify(fs.readFile);

(async () => {
  await shell.exec("node external.js", { async: true });
  const data = await read('Hello.txt');
  // do something with data...
})();
```

Please tell me if it is possible to implement this task, and how can this be done? Thanks for attention!

Comment: You would need to make some assumptions about how the scripts behave. They might create promises that never settle, for example `new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {})`. How would you want to treat such cases? Can't you just wait until the `node external.js` process exits? See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75450434/attaching-end-listener-to-filestream-in-a-promise.

Comment: In my case, I use only file operations in the launched script - fs methods. There will be no other promises. It is important to me first of all that the promises are completed, (resolved or rejected), at least

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `external.js` performs a file operation, then the `node external.js` process will only exit after the file operation has completed. Therefore

```js
await util.promisify(child_process.exec)("node external.js");
```

should fulfill your requirement.